# Consistent SQL database snapshot using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to export a snapshot of a postgresql database to parquet files using Spark.
I am dumping each table in the database to a seperate parquet file.

```
tables_names = ["A", "B", "C" , ...]

for table_name in tables_names:
    table = (spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", driver)
    .option("url", url)
    .option("dbtable", table_name)
    .option("user", user)    
    .load())
    table.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(table_name)
```

The problem, however, is that I need the tables to be consistent with each other.
Ideally, the table loads should be executed in a single transaction so they see the same version of the database.

The only solution I can think of is to select all tables in a single query using `UNION/JOIN` but then I would need to identify each table columns which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: No is also an answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [Postgres pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) to create an offline copy of your database, and then have Spark copy that snapshot. "Dumps created by pg_dump are internally consistent..."

Answer (score 0):

Unless you force all future connections to the database, not instance, to be read only and terminate those in flight, using, setting the
PostgreSQL configuration parameter `default_transaction_read_only` to true, then, no you cannot do this per discrete table approach as per your code.

Note that a session can override the global setting.

Means your 2nd option will work due to MVRCM, but not elegant and how performance from a Spark context for jdbc?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't force other transactions to be read_only. 
What do you mean by MVRCM?

Comment: Multi version read consistency model like oracle. Second part of answer holds as you state yourself.